# How to map two tables in database PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a project in which a user can save their own coupon codes on the website, so I want to know what is the best way to do that.

Lets say, I have 1 table with the users, like this:

```
userId  |  firstName  | lastName  | codeId
```

And then I have a table of the coupon codes, like this:

```
codeId  |  codeNumber
```

So what I can do is to connect the `codeId` to `userId` so when someone saves the coupons the `codeId` from the coupon table goes into the `codeId` of the users table.

But now what do I do if when user has multiple coupons? How should they be connected to the user?

I have 2 options what to do:

1. Saving the `codeId` from coupons table into the `codeId` of users table like `1,2,3,4,5`,
2. Make a new row into the coupons table and connect the user to the code by adding another field in the coupon table `userId` and putting into it the `userId` of the user which has added the coupon.

So which of the two options is better?

Comment: So multiple users can share the same coupon code, and each user can have multiple codes? (A many-to-many relationship)

Comment: Yes, this will also be an option to do on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship between two tables should be solved by adding a third table connecting the two:

```
user_coupons
- userId
- couponId
```

Comment: Thank you Emil, this would be the best solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option violates the 1-NF rule, where it says that no column will have a group of values.

This is a typical one-to-many relationship. Your second option of creating a separate table User_Coupons (not the the underscore) and create a row with UserID, CouponCode, for each association. The two columns together should be unique so that they both become the primary key of the associative table.

Comment: one-to-many is a bad model for this IMO, coupon codes should likely have information associated with them. Such as the product/website they are discounting, expiration dates, etc. This would also serve to circumvent duplicate records. Users would just be associated to existing records.
many-to-many is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If i was you my database will be:

```
userId  |  firstName  | lastName

codeNumber | userId
```

You can insert many codeNumber for any user if you want.